# Make Html <img src={} /> render a base64 image which accepts different file format

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello everyone i have a base64encoded string and i want to render it inside a html tag in the src attribute . I basically found a solution to render it but the problem is i need it to accept other file formats.

File formats i need are :  .svg , .jpg, .png, .jpeg ect ... which may be added later .

I can't seem to create a function which will make this file format value dynamic .

I'm trying to make one with a switch case but can't seem to do it . Can someone help me realize this ?

```html
<img
  className={styles.img__box}
  src={`data:image/png;base64,${headerIcon}`}
  alt="icon"
/>
```

This is how you can render a base64 inside a img src , but as you can see it's only accepting png , i want to make it accept dynamic values

Comment: Will your code be able to know whether it's png, jpg, etc? It's not possible otherwise.

Comment: Where do you get that encoded image? Did you encode a binary file?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the MIME (Media Type)

```js
const mime = 'image/jpg';
<img
  className={styles.img__box}
  src={`data:${mime};base64,${headerIcon}`}
  alt="icon"
/>
```

Comment: Hey i found the solution yesterday , i was spliting the mime part on my base64 converter function which was the wrong thing to do . As someone said to me that the base64 string should also include the mime in front . Maybe if i shared the whole code it would have been easiers , anyway thanks for your time .